# SSIS how to handle EST timezone from source file

Tags: sql, database, ssis

Source is CSV file and having multiple columns

One column is updated_at having values like "2019-11-09T00:12:17Z"

I have loaded file in stage table using SSIS with datetime as datatype at package level but in stage I am getting results like "2019-11-09 00:00:00"

But I am expecting result like "2019-11-09 00:12:17" into stage table .... pls help

Comment: It sounds like the value is getting converted to a `date` at some point, but you don't provide enough information to actually help.

Comment: Gordon Linoff Its simple one-to-one mapping to load data from CSV to table in ssis

Comment: Run the package in Visual Studio and check the data path right after CSV File Source with Data Viewer. Check the data in the Data Viewer for possible truncation in the source, and attach the screenshot to your problem.